# Tensorflow image recognition identify similarity percentage of one type of image type/class

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition

What do you call the image recognition that will identify the accuracy/similarity percentage of one type of image type/class? When I try searching, all of the examples are image classifiers, in which they classify the image for atleast 2 types (eg: dog or cat). I just want to identify the percentage how similar the my test image to a dog. (but not cat).

Just to make things clear, I'm asking for the name of that type of process, not the exact code how to make one. I tried searching with **Image Recognition** search query, but they always give my **Image Classifier** in which it identifies the image category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an output of softmax layer at the end of your network you will get a set of *probabilities*. For [cat, dog, bird] it might be something like [0.1, 0.7, 0.2] (all the values would add up to 100%). Unfortunately, there is not way to ensure that this similarity has anything to do with the real world. Some networks would always output extremely high value for one class (as [0.001, 0.9987, 0.0003]).

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any workaround like putting some null/empty category that will receive the 100% if is not similar to my category that I want to classify?

Comment: @TentenPonce that would be similar to using another class during training [cat, dog, bird, other]

Comment: Hm, I'll share what I want to achieve, the user will open up the camera, while the user moves it, it must detect if my desire image is in there. If softmax layer will always return to a sum of 100, then there's a chance that my desire image will have the highest probability even though it is not there. I think this method is not new, maybe I'm just looking in the wrong topic, would you know what kind of topic is this?